# Rails app deploys successfully, but heroku run ls returns empty

Tags: heroku

After success deployment, the dyno crashes:

```
Starting process with command `puma -p \44453 -C ./config/puma.rb`
2023-12-05T07:49:39.910964+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-6.3.0/lib/puma/dsl.rb:133:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ./config/puma.rb (Errno::ENOENT)
```

Upon running heroku run ls, no results are returned

Running git remote show heroku returns:

```
* remote heroku
  Fetch URL: https://git.heroku.com/x3b-docs.git
  Push  URL: https://git.heroku.com/x3b-docs.git
  HEAD branch: main
  Remote branches:
    main   tracked
    master new (next fetch will store in remotes/heroku)
  Local ref configured for 'git push':


main pushes to main (up to date)
```

I can't figure out why the deployment succeeds at 140mb, yet the files are not present.

Here are the last few lines from the build:

```
-----> Detecting rails configuration
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> web
       Default types for buildpack -> console, rake
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 138.8M
-----> Launching...
       Released v168
```

Comment: The output of `git remote show heroku` lists both `main` and `master` branches. Which one contains your code?